# Testing QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter

Tags: usb, kernel-modules, serial-port

I have `Kubuntu 14.10` development workstation and recently I have bought a   [QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial](http://www.wch-ic.com/search?t=all&q=CH340) adapter. `HL-340 is USB<---->Serial adapter` and it **is recognised by my kernel**:

```
user@comp001:~$ lsusb
    Bus 007 Device 010: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter
[..]
```

I am trying to initiate communication via this adapter with `Raspberry Pi B+` board, but I am constantly failing.

Whatever text I send to the `Raspberry Pi B+` via `minicom`, the traffic on the line is dead, I've checked with scope. I've double checked the `Raspberry Pi B+ setup`, the wirings (triple checked with multimeter), the scope wirings and the serial communication is dead. The port on `Raspberry Pi B+` is working, because I've hooked up scope on transmit pin of serial port (on  Raspberry Pi B+ side) and if I send text from `Raspberry Pi B+` (via `minicom` under `ssh` tunnel), I get activity on the scope.

I **cannot get data from PC** via `USB serial dongle`. How do I test if the dongle works?

Comment: How are using `minicom`? What port / baudrate? Are the Raspberry Pi serial levels *real* RS232 levels (-5/+5V) or are they TTL levels (0/5V)? And is the device *really* recognized by your kernel (check `dmesg` output after plugging)? `lsusb` simply shows whatever is connected, even if the device is not supported.

Comment: I have one of these too, the output is not at rs232 signal levels (instead 0V and 5V) and the UART seems to only return the low 5 bits of the input. It doesn't work correctly on raspberry pi or on amd64, probably a counterfeit chip.

Comment: I compared operation against a known-good PL2303 based serial port,

Comment: @KernelPanic the link is broken.

Comment: @JonasStein at the time of writing this question the link was valid, I've updated it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the adapter loading the right kernel module? I've heard that your device may be CH341 compatible:

```
sudo modprobe ch341
```

Comment: should really do lsmod first to confirm that that the module has not loaded automatically.

Comment: true, but unless there's already a kernel rule to load the module, it's not going to guess that these two devices are compatible

Answer (score 6):

`lsusb` lists the device here as

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter
```

It is often shipped together with the `sds011` sensor. 
The required kernel module is called `ch341` and built with the following `.config` entry:

```
CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_CH341=m
```

If you use `make nconfig` or `make menuconfig` you will find this module in

```
-> Device Drivers
   -> USB support (USB_SUPPORT [=y]) 
      -> USB Serial Converter support
```

I had to set the communication parameters manually to 9600 baud, 8N1 before I could use the device properly:

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 raw
```